# Disappearing images in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

In a landing page for a chrome extension, after the user installs the extension I show a popup that has an explanation on how to proceed. The popup contains images (that are served from a different CDN), the popup uses css animations and transitions when it appears.

Sometimes (not sure exactly when), even though the images are loaded (and visible in the dev tools) they are not displayed in the popup. I have tried changing it from css background-images to  elements, I've tried updating the images src after the extension is added, and also to remove some of the animations, but it doesn't seem to fix this issue.

http://live.rounds.com/x-factor/

has anyone encountered a similar issue and knows how to fix or bypass it?

[image]

Comment: Images has right network status (200 or 304), content-type?

Comment: yes, they are also visible in the devtools when I hover the path

Comment: Add info from Network tab, because then you hover in devtools, for example, from styles sidebar image can download in browser background again.

Comment: @Pinal, added image to the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have deal with same issue and only that works for me was removing -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; from animate.css body tag